# Java: line-stroke with filled shape

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, stroke

This is not really important, but it was bothering me for a little while.

**Problem description:** 
*Given:* a line (Line2D) 
*Wanted:* drawing the line as a wedge (Filled GeneralPath)

Surely this can be done by creating the wedge as General Path and then filling it by the Graphics (my solution).

My first approach would have been a wedge-stroked line, because I didn't want to change the line object for some reason, also I just wanted to draw the line object and not think about it any more. 
Creating the wedge-stroke was no problem (Some calculations and then creating the General Path) - **but I was not able to fill it (easily)**

Apparently it seems the fill of Graphics2D only fills the shape it gets - and does not handle the filling of the stroke (that behavior makes sense if one thinks about it).

**Question:** Is there any way to fill a shape of a Stroke (filling a shape - more specifically: a GeneralPath - somehow before drawing it)?

Answer (score 3):

May be `BasicStroke.public Shape createStrokedShape(Shape s)` can help if you pass the Line2D there?

Answer (score 3):

Once you use `createStrokedShape()`, note that [`draw()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#fill%28java.awt.Shape%29) "strokes the outline of a `Shape`," while [`fill()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#draw%28java.awt.Shapee%29) "fills the interior of a `Shape`."

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.awt.*;

public static Shape strokeToShape(Shape path, float strokeWidth)
    return new BasicStroke(strokeWidth).createStrokedShape(path);
}
```

You may also specify `cap` and `join` parameters of `BasicStroke`